# Okta AJAX Get Error - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in ExtJs

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, okta, okta-api

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'https://dev-516799.oktapreview.com/api/v1/users?limit=200',
        method: 'GET',
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'SSWS Token' 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            //'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET'
        },
        scope: this,
        cleanup: function () {
            view.setLoading(false);
        },
        success: function (response) {
}
```

But I am getting error as "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

Comment: Can you please create a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor). So I can understand the problem better and help you out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`Access-control: Allow-Origin` headers are a security feature that has to be enabled in the **reply** from the server, not in the request to the server.

Examples: [ExtJS - Adding headers to AJAX store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37439967/extjs-adding-headers-to-ajax-store/37442428#37442428)

In your case, you are at the mercy of Okta. [They have some APIs that support CORS if you provide them with the allowed URLs](https://developer.okta.com/docs/api/getting_started/enabling_cors), and others that don't. You cannot access Okta APIs directly from your JavaScript code unless the APIs are marked as CORS-enabled and you have added your URL to the list of CORS-enabled URLs in the Okta admin panel. If you need unmarked APIs or access from arbitrary URLs, you may have to create a wrapper in your own server backend that relays the requests from your frontend to the Okta server.